# Cannot boot after last kernel update (Fedora 23)

Tags: fedora, boot

I have a Fedora 23 machine which worked well up to kernel 4.2.8-300. I updated to 4.3.3-300 and 4.3.3-301 and with both I cannot boot. Not even in single user mode.

The only thing I see on the screen is:

[image]

I don't see any error. Any idea on what the problem could be?

**Edit**

As one of the last messages was about `plymouth`, just to be sure, I booted with an old kernel and completely removed it. No changes.

**Edit 2**

`grub.cfg` entries seem the same (but for the version number).

The working one:

```
menuentry 'Fedora (4.2.8-300.fc23.i686+PAE) 23 (Twenty Three)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-14f2ed60-6348-41b7-ade0-a4849a0d4d5a' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  4001c5e3-fb16-4c71-9291-c48fd94ddc14
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4001c5e3-fb16-4c71-9291-c48fd94ddc14
    fi
    echo 'Loading Fedora (4.2.8-300.fc23.i686+PAE) 23 (Twenty Three)'
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.2.8-300.fc23.i686+PAE root=/dev/vg_matteo2/lv_root ro quiet rhgb LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd /initramfs-4.2.8-300.fc23.i686+PAE.img
}
```

The new one:

```
menuentry 'Fedora (4.3.3-301.fc23.i686+PAE) 23 (Twenty Three)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-14f2ed60-6348-41b7-ade0-a4849a0d4d5a' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  4001c5e3-fb16-4c71-9291-c48fd94ddc14
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4001c5e3-fb16-4c71-9291-c48fd94ddc14
    fi
    echo 'Loading Fedora (4.3.3-301.fc23.i686+PAE) 23 (Twenty Three)'
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.3.3-301.fc23.i686+PAE root=/dev/vg_matteo2/lv_root ro quiet rhgb LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd /initramfs-4.3.3-301.fc23.i686+PAE.img
}
```

As I can access to the console only via VMWare Client on Citrix accessing the serial console will not be so easy ...

**Edit 3**

Summary of the kernels:

- 4.2.8-300 boots (no problems)
- 4.3.3-300 does **not** boot
- 4.3.3-301 does **not** boot
- 4.3.3-303 does **not** boot
- 4.3.5-300 does **not** boot

**Edit 4**

Tested with the newly released kernel `4.3.4-300`: still the same problem

As one of the last messages is about DRM I tried (without success) to disable it:

```
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.3.4-300.fc23.i686+PAE root=/dev/vg_matteo2/lv_root ro LANG=en_US.UTF-8 vga=normal nofb nomodeset video=vesafb:off i915.modeset=0 3
```

But the problem still persists and the last messages are still the same

**Edit 5**

As suggested I tried with `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` but I get

```
vmwgfx 0000:00:0f.0: BAR 1: can't reserve [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
```

[image]

**Edit 6**

With the new kernel (4.4.2-301) and `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` I am still not able to boot but at least the output on the console is readable:

[image]

and some info is written to `/var/log/messages/`:

```
Feb 29 13:23:59 matteo kernel: [drm] Legacy Display Unit initialized
Feb 29 13:23:59 matteo kernel: [drm] width 1600
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: [drm] height 1200
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: [drm] bpp 32
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: [drm] Fifo max 0x00040000 min 0x00001000 cap 0x0000007f
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: [drm] DX: no.
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: fb: switching to svgadrmfb from VESA VGA
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: fbcon: svgadrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: fbcon_init: detected unhandled fb_set_par error, error code -22
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 200x75
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000068
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: IP: [<f8a97c12>] vmw_fb_setcolreg+0x22/0xb0 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: *pdpt = 00000000369fc001 *pde = 0000000000000000 
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: Modules linked in: crc32c_intel vmw_balloon joydev vmwgfx(+) ttm drm_kms_helper i2c_piix4 parport_pc vmw_vmci parport drm acpi_cpufreq tpm_tis tpm nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd gr
ace sunrpc mptspi scsi_transport_spi mptscsih e1000 mptbase serio_raw ata_generic pata_acpi fjes
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 617 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 4.4.2-301.fc23.i686+PAE #1
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/17/2015
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: task: f6b21000 ti: f6b40000 task.ti: f6b40000
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: EIP: 0060:[<f8a97c12>] EFLAGS: 00010293 CPU: 1
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: EIP is at vmw_fb_setcolreg+0x22/0xb0 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: EAX: 00000000 EBX: f104235c ECX: 00000000 EDX: 00000000
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: ESI: 00000000 EDI: 00000000 EBP: f6b418c4 ESP: f6b418a8
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: CR0: 80050033 CR2: 00000068 CR3: 327e8640 CR4: 000006f0
Feb 29 13:24:00 matteo kernel: Stack:
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: f6b418c0 00000082 00000021 00000000 00000000 00000000 f8a97bf0 f6b41908
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: c07b95bd 00000000 0000ffff f1042000 c102cc40 c102cc60 c102cc80 00000000
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: c0e381dc 0000ffff 00000000 f1042000 f8a97bf0 f1042000 f703c204 f703c204
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: Call Trace:
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f8a97bf0>] ? vmw_fb_fillrect+0x40/0x40 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07b95bd>] fb_set_cmap+0xed/0x130
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f8a97bf0>] ? vmw_fb_fillrect+0x40/0x40 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07a93d0>] fbcon_set_palette+0x130/0x160
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07ac069>] fbcon_switch+0x3c9/0x630
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c082e0b3>] redraw_screen+0x163/0x250
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c082ecd9>] do_bind_con_driver+0x269/0x350
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c082f0ce>] do_take_over_console+0x13e/0x1b0
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07aa0cf>] do_fbcon_takeover+0x5f/0xc0
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07aebb7>] fbcon_event_notify+0x687/0x780
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c048ccce>] notifier_call_chain+0x4e/0x70
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c048d019>] __blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x39/0x60
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c048d05f>] blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x1f/0x30
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07b3ec6>] fb_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07b5de1>] register_framebuffer+0x1f1/0x330
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f8a98b0b>] vmw_fb_init+0x39b/0x440 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f8a97412>] vmw_driver_load+0xd72/0xfc0 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f89bfb6e>] drm_dev_register+0x8e/0xa0 [drm]
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f89c1fd9>] drm_get_pci_dev+0x79/0x1c0 [drm]
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f8a95b22>] vmw_probe+0x12/0x20 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07888cb>] pci_device_probe+0x7b/0xf0
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c086c969>] ? devices_kset_move_last+0x49/0xa0
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c0870259>] driver_probe_device+0x1f9/0x490
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c063ed77>] ? sysfs_create_dir_ns+0x37/0x90
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c07885a1>] ? pci_match_device+0xc1/0xe0
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c0870569>] __driver_attach+0x79/0x80
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c08704f0>] ? driver_probe_device+0x490/0x490
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c086e0e7>] bus_for_each_dev+0x57/0xa0
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c086fa9e>] driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c08704f0>] ? driver_probe_device+0x490/0x490
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c086f63f>] bus_add_driver+0x1ef/0x290
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f899f000>] ? 0xf899f000
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<f899f000>] ? 0xf899f000
Feb 29 13:24:01 matteo kernel: [<c0870d6d>] driver_register+0x5d/0xf0
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c07870b3>] __pci_register_driver+0x33/0x40
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<f89c21fd>] drm_pci_init+0xdd/0x100 [drm]
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<f899f000>] ? 0xf899f000
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<f899f013>] vmwgfx_init+0x13/0x1000 [vmwgfx]
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c040211a>] do_one_initcall+0xaa/0x200
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<f899f000>] ? 0xf899f000
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c05ba3e9>] ? kfree+0x119/0x130
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c05a4eb5>] ? __vunmap+0xa5/0xf0
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c05b9875>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x165/0x1d0
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c0568ac7>] ? do_init_module+0x21/0x1b5
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c0568ac7>] ? do_init_module+0x21/0x1b5
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c0568af6>] do_init_module+0x50/0x1b5
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c04f5393>] load_module+0x1dd3/0x23d0
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c05a524e>] ? __vmalloc_node_range+0x14e/0x240
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c04f5abf>] SyS_init_module+0x12f/0x190
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c040382d>] do_fast_syscall_32+0x8d/0x150
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: [<c0b12418>] sysenter_past_esp+0x3d/0x61
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: Code: 5e 5d c3 8d b6 00 00 00 00 55 89 e5 57 56 53 83 ec 10 66 66 66 66 90 83 f8 0f 89 55 f0 77 72 8b 5d 10 8b 9b 4c 03 00 00 8b 7b 3c <8b> 77 68 83 fe 18 74 2e 83 fe 20 74 29 8b 47 6c 89 74 24 04 c7
Feb 29 13:24:02 matteo kernel: EIP: [<f8a97c12>] vmw_fb_setcolreg+0x22/0xb0 [vmwgfx] SS:ESP 0068:f6b418a8
```

Comment: What changed in between the grub-config for these kernels? also did you try to enable a serial console at boot, and see what the kernel prints there? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79838/grub-and-usb-serial-support

Comment: is it possible to paste ALL the bootlog (from kernel / initrd load on..) ?

Comment: @gerhardd. As the boot stops before being able to log in (on the console or remotely) I cannot copy an paste the output. The output is pretty fast and I could try to record the screen over the remote console. I really don't have any clue on how to get more information

Comment: I'm guessing, since Plymouth and DRM appear to be involved, that this is a video/display issue. What display driver are you emulating in your vmware client?

Comment: I had the same problem,  had to resort to booting the previous kernel.

Comment: What does `abrt-cli list` show?

Comment: @RayM nothing relevant: the last entry is a crash from ccze from two days earlier

Comment: I would recommend booting using an older kernel and then upgrading. There are various fixes about drm, intel and booting issues, https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/?packages=kernel

Comment: @Braiam I tried. Booting with 4.2.8-300 works. I removed the new one and re-installed it. With all the newer kernels (4.3.3-300, 4.3.3-301 and 4.3.3-303) it does not boot.

Comment: I was talking about the ones in testing (kernel-4.3.4-200.fc22, kernel-4.3.4-300.fc22), have you tried those?

Comment: @Braiam Ooops, thanks for the hint. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on both my servers running F23 server edition. I updated to kernel 4.3.4-300 and rebooted but this resulted in the servers being completely freezed. I had to reboot using an old kernel 4.2.6-301.

Could not see the booting messages when hitting ESC button.
Looked like plymouth was stalled also.

I then installed kernel 4.3.5-300 (from updates-testing) on both servers but only one succeeded to boot on that new kernel.

I got this :

```
# abrt-cli list
id 29e33b5c96e28619dca309942a505fc8e2ef19e2
reason:         BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000060
time:           Fri 05 Feb 2016 03:35:14 PM CET
cmdline:        BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.3.4-300.fc23.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
count:          882
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/oops-2016-02-05-15:35:10-1606-4
Reported:       cannot be reported
```

I don't have these problems with kernel 4.3.4-301 installed on our desktops running F23 workstation edition.

Comment: I tried with 4.3.5-300 and got the same result. `art-cli list` ist not showing anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

On kernel version above 4.2.8 add `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` instruction.
You can do it in `grub-customize` in General setting, or pressing `e` in kernel selection menu on boot, add new line and then press `Ctrl + X` to continue boot, but it will bee only for current boot.

Comment: I tried, still not booting but the error message at least is confirming that the issue is related to vmwgfx

Comment: on my physical this did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

On ESXi increasing the VM video memory from 5MB to 8MB resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Why the down vote? I will try ..

Comment: I tried with 8MB: no changes ...

Comment: Did I down vote my own answer? Are you still able to ssh to the VM with the console unresponsive? I didn't notice the issue until I booted a new clone and tried to grab the DHCP address from the console.

Comment: No the machine is not reachable by network (not even pingable)